# Hibernate mapping, set objects read as modified

Tags: java, hibernate

On my project, I noticed recently that a recent mapping lead to a specific behavior of "Reglement" object (sorry, french code)

When we read "Reglement" object without having any modification sub objects "ventilationDepenses" are deleted and created again, so "Reglement" Object is set state (version) as modified

```
Hibernate: update MOUVEMENT_FINANCIER set DATE_VERSION=?, COMMENTAIRE=?, DATE_ANNULATION=?, DATE_CREATION=?, TYPE=?, MODE_PAIEMENT=?, MONTANT_MOUVEMENT=?, NATURE=?, STATUT=?, DATE_CHEQUE=?, NUMERO_CHEQUE=?, INDIVIDUAL_OPERATION_ID=?, DATE_AUTORISATION=?, FRANCHISE=?, INDEMNISATION_PLUS=?, INDEMNITE_FORFAITAIRE=?, MONTANT_PROPOSE=?, OBJET_REGLEMENT=?, REFERENCE_LIEE=?, SOLDE_REGLEMENTS_BENEFICIAIRE=?, TAUX_T1=?, TAUX_T2=?, TAUX_T3=?, TAUX_TU=?, TYPE_BENEFICIAIRE=?, TYPE_DESTINATAIRE=?, EST_SOUMIS_TVA=?, PK_MVT_FINANCIER_LIE=?, DATE_TRAITEMENT_BATCH=?, BORDEREAU_ID=?, TRANSACTION_ID=?, PK_PERSONNE_BENEFICIAIRE=?, PK_ACTEUR_BENEFICIAIRE=?, PK_ADD_COUR_REG_BENEF=?, PK_PERSONNE_DESTINATAIRE=?, PK_ACTEUR_DESTINATAIRE=?, PK_ADD_COUR_REG_DEST=?, PK_RIB=? where PK_MOUVEMENT_FINANCIER=? and DATE_VERSION=?
Hibernate: update MOUVEMENT_FINANCIER set DATE_VERSION=?, COMMENTAIRE=?, DATE_ANNULATION=?, DATE_CREATION=?, TYPE=?, MODE_PAIEMENT=?, MONTANT_MOUVEMENT=?, NATURE=?, STATUT=?, DATE_CHEQUE=?, NUMERO_CHEQUE=?, INDIVIDUAL_OPERATION_ID=?, DATE_AUTORISATION=?, FRANCHISE=?, INDEMNISATION_PLUS=?, INDEMNITE_FORFAITAIRE=?, MONTANT_PROPOSE=?, OBJET_REGLEMENT=?, REFERENCE_LIEE=?, SOLDE_REGLEMENTS_BENEFICIAIRE=?, TAUX_T1=?, TAUX_T2=?, TAUX_T3=?, TAUX_TU=?, TYPE_BENEFICIAIRE=?, TYPE_DESTINATAIRE=?, EST_SOUMIS_TVA=?, PK_MVT_FINANCIER_LIE=?, DATE_TRAITEMENT_BATCH=?, BORDEREAU_ID=?, TRANSACTION_ID=?, PK_PERSONNE_BENEFICIAIRE=?, PK_ACTEUR_BENEFICIAIRE=?, PK_ADD_COUR_REG_BENEF=?, PK_PERSONNE_DESTINATAIRE=?, PK_ACTEUR_DESTINATAIRE=?, PK_ADD_COUR_REG_DEST=?, PK_RIB=? where PK_MOUVEMENT_FINANCIER=? and DATE_VERSION=?
Hibernate: update MOUVEMENT_FINANCIER set DATE_VERSION=?, COMMENTAIRE=?, DATE_ANNULATION=?, DATE_CREATION=?, TYPE=?, MODE_PAIEMENT=?, MONTANT_MOUVEMENT=?, NATURE=?, STATUT=?, DATE_CHEQUE=?, NUMERO_CHEQUE=?, INDIVIDUAL_OPERATION_ID=?, DATE_AUTORISATION=?, FRANCHISE=?, INDEMNISATION_PLUS=?, INDEMNITE_FORFAITAIRE=?, MONTANT_PROPOSE=?, OBJET_REGLEMENT=?, REFERENCE_LIEE=?, SOLDE_REGLEMENTS_BENEFICIAIRE=?, TAUX_T1=?, TAUX_T2=?, TAUX_T3=?, TAUX_TU=?, TYPE_BENEFICIAIRE=?, TYPE_DESTINATAIRE=?, EST_SOUMIS_TVA=?, PK_MVT_FINANCIER_LIE=?, DATE_TRAITEMENT_BATCH=?, BORDEREAU_ID=?, TRANSACTION_ID=?, PK_PERSONNE_BENEFICIAIRE=?, PK_ACTEUR_BENEFICIAIRE=?, PK_ADD_COUR_REG_BENEF=?, PK_PERSONNE_DESTINATAIRE=?, PK_ACTEUR_DESTINATAIRE=?, PK_ADD_COUR_REG_DEST=?, PK_RIB=? where PK_MOUVEMENT_FINANCIER=? and DATE_VERSION=?
Hibernate: delete from VENTILATION_DEPENSES where PK_MOUVEMENT_FINANCIER=?
Hibernate: insert into VENTILATION_DEPENSES (PK_MOUVEMENT_FINANCIER, CODE_NATURE_DEPENSE, MONTANT_DEPENSE, COMMENTAIRE_DEPENSE) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: delete from VENTILATION_DEPENSES where PK_MOUVEMENT_FINANCIER=?
Hibernate: insert into VENTILATION_DEPENSES (PK_MOUVEMENT_FINANCIER, CODE_NATURE_DEPENSE, MONTANT_DEPENSE, COMMENTAIRE_DEPENSE) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: delete from VENTILATION_DEPENSES where PK_MOUVEMENT_FINANCIER=?
Hibernate: insert into VENTILATION_DEPENSES (PK_MOUVEMENT_FINANCIER, CODE_NATURE_DEPENSE, MONTANT_DEPENSE, COMMENTAIRE_DEPENSE) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into VENTILATION_DEPENSES (PK_MOUVEMENT_FINANCIER, CODE_NATURE_DEPENSE, MONTANT_DEPENSE, COMMENTAIRE_DEPENSE) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

It seems to be linked with the mapping of "ventilationDepenses" especially lazy=false. I would like to understand what's going on and what is wrong in our mapping.

Here is part of the mapping.

```
        <id name="pk" type="integer" column="PK_MOUVEMENT_FINANCIER" unsaved-value="null">
            <generator class="com.prima.solutions.primaclaims.core.dao.impl.PkGenerator">
                <param name="table">SEQUENCE</param>
                <param name="primary_key_column">ENTITE</param>
                <param name="primary_key_value">MOUVEMENT_FINANCIER</param>
                <param name="value_column">NUMERO</param>
            </generator>
        </id>

        <discriminator column="CLASSE" type="integer" />
        <timestamp column="DATE_VERSION" name="version" unsaved-value="null" />

        <property name="commentaire" column="COMMENTAIRE" />
        <property name="dateAnnulation" type="timestamp" column="DATE_ANNULATION" />
        ....

        <subclass name="com.prima.solutions.primaclaims.core.modele.sinistre.financier.Encaissement" discriminator-value="2">
            <property name="natureRecuperation" column="NATURE_RECUPERATION" />
            <property name="typeEmetteur" column="TYPE_EMETTEUR" />
            <property name="bankName" column="NOM_BANQUE" />
            <property name="accountOwner" column="TITULAIRE_COMPTE" />
            <property name="transferLabel" column="LIBELLE_VIREMENT" />

            ....
        </subclass>

        <subclass name="com.prima.solutions.primaclaims.core.modele.sinistre.financier.Reglement" discriminator-value="1">
            <property name="dateAutorisation" type="timestamp" column="DATE_AUTORISATION" />
            <property name="franchise" column="FRANCHISE" />
            <property name="indemnisationPlus" column="INDEMNISATION_PLUS" />
            <property name="indemniteForfaitaire" column="INDEMNITE_FORFAITAIRE" />
            ...

            <many-to-one name="beneficiaire" column="PK_PERSONNE_BENEFICIAIRE"
                class="com.prima.solutions.primaclaims.core.modele.referentiel.personne.Personne" cascade="none" fetch="join" lazy="false"/>

            ...

            <set name="ventilationDepenses" table="VENTILATION_DEPENSES" cascade="all,delete-orphan" lazy="false">
                <key column="PK_MOUVEMENT_FINANCIER" not-null="true" />
                <composite-element class="com.prima.solutions.primaclaims.core.modele.sinistre.financier.Depense">
                    <property name="nature" column="CODE_NATURE_DEPENSE"/>
                    <property name="montant" column="MONTANT_DEPENSE" />
                    <property name="version" column="DATE_VERSION"/>
                    <property name="commentaire" column="COMMENTAIRE_DEPENSE"/>
                </composite-element>
            </set>
        </subclass>

    </class>
```

Answer (score 0):

After somme investigations it seems that using a composite-element causes delete / insert statement at the of of a transaction.

Mapping has been changed to define a  one to many mapping and an entity class for our object "VentilationDepenses"

```
<class name="com.prima.solutions.primaclaims.core.modele.sinistre.financier.MouvementFinancier" table="MOUVEMENT_FINANCIER"
    discriminator-value="0" abstract="true">
    ...

    <subclass name="com.prima.solutions.primaclaims.core.modele.sinistre.financier.Reglement" discriminator-value="1">
    ...
        <set name="ventilationDepenses" cascade="all,delete-orphan" fetch="join">
            <key column="PK_MOUVEMENT_FINANCIER" />
            <one-to-many class="com.prima.solutions.primaclaims.core.modele.sinistre.financier.Depense"/>
        </set>
    </subclass>

</class>

<class name="com.prima.solutions.primaclaims.core.modele.sinistre.financier.Depense" table="VENTILATION_DEPENSES">
    <composite-id>
        <key-property name="pkReglement" column="PK_MOUVEMENT_FINANCIER" />
        <key-property name="nature" column="CODE_NATURE_DEPENSE"/>
    </composite-id>

    <timestamp column="DATE_VERSION" name="version" unsaved-value="null" />

    <property name="montant" column="MONTANT_DEPENSE" />
    <property name="commentaire" column="COMMENTAIRE_DEPENSE" />
</class>
```